# To prove:$b^{\frac{1}{p}}-a^{\frac{1}{p}} \le (b-a)^{\frac{1}{p}}$

Tags: calculus

if$$p\ge1,0<a<b.$$How to prove?thx~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $b - a = c$, then $b^{\frac{1}{p}} \leq a^{\frac{1}{p}} + c^{\frac{1}{p}}$, and:

$1 \leq x^{\frac{1}{p}} + y^{\frac{1}{p}} = x^{\frac{1}{p}} + (1-x)^{\frac{1}{p}} = f(x)$.

You can take derivative and go from here filling in the details if interested.